# How to chage background color in jQuery

Tags: jquery-mobile

This is my jquery sample code below it uses default view.  How can I change my background color? also button color? How to use custom css file please tell me
    
      
    
        
        Intro to jQuery Mobile

```
    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Facebook Friends</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
           <p>

           <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

              <li>
              <a href="index.html">Get Friends</a>
              </li>

              <li>
              <a href="index.html">Post to Wall</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="index.html">Send Message</a></li>
           </ul>

           </p>

        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
         </html>
```

Comment: How about reading up a little on JQM first? http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery-mobile-forms/

Comment: but tel me how to use custom css file?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use themeroller. It is accessible here:
[themeroller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/)

Set up your custom theme and try to add this line to the header of index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />
```

It should work.
If you want to change background in a different way try to add to your page div's this line:

```
<style>body {background-color:#b0c4de;}</style>
```